# OpenGL Native Plug-In Error with Unity on Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl-es, google-vr, daydream

I am on a Unity 5.6.5f1 project targeting Android 6.0. The project is VR enabled with Daydream without the gvr sdk since I do not need any interaction.

I noticed that most of the time, when I launch the application, I get the stereo view but everything is black, I do not even see the splash screen and in logcat I get the following error:

> 'E/Unity: OPENGL NATIVE PLUG-IN ERROR: GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: Framebuffer is not complete or incompatible with command'

However, 30% of the time, when I launch the application it works fine and I do not get this error.

So basically I open and close the app until it is working..

Any idea where it could come from? I am using multi pass rendering.

Comment: Are you calling `VRSettings.LoadDeviceByNam` anywhere in your scripts?

Comment: I did but then I removed it and now my app is only running in Daydream mode. I am going to check of I did not let this call somewhere.

Comment: It's one of the cause of this. If you have already removed it then make sure that OpenGL(not Vulkan) is set as the default graphics in the build settings.

Comment: I checked "Auto Graphics API", which version of OpenGl should I pick if I uncheck this? (I can't check my code right now, i will do that tonight)

Comment: Uncheck the "Auto Graphics API" and make sure that OpenGLES2 is at the top. I also suggest you update Unity if the problem still persist

Comment: @Programmer Thank you, it looks like it solved my issue on my Android 6.0 device, moreover, it removed an other OPENGL error (GL_INVALID_ENUM) I always had.
However I am also targetting an Android 7.0 device. This device didn't have the black screen issue but I still tried with OpenGLES2 but it broked the textures (everything is stretched), any idea why?

Comment: I talked too fast, I restarted the app 10 times in a row without issue, but then 10 minutes later, black screen again with GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION again.

Comment: No other ideas. Try updating Unity. It could be a bug that has been fixed