# Issues in AR App built in Unity using Vuforia SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have created a small application in Unity using Vuforia SDK. It recognizes an image and projects a 3D model on the top of it.
I am able to run the app in Unity Editor but getting an issue when I try to create an iOS project and run the app on device.

I am trying to run it on iPhone X (iOS version 11.3) and this is the error that I am getting when the app starts:

> VideoBackgroundConfig with screen size of zero received, skipping
>   config step

I searched the issue on net but the solutions that I got didn't work. I am using Vuforia version 7.0.47, Unity version 2017.3.1f1 Personal and XCode version 9.3 beta 4.

Could someone please provide some pointers?

Comment: Can you double check if you are using opengles2.0 as renderer in iOS redering API? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49364458/opengl-error-with-unity-on-android
The link above points to similer error but in android. 
'Uncheck the "Auto Graphics API" and make sure that OpenGLES2 is at the top.' Try this and let us also know what more solutions you have tried yet so we can help you. 

Note: This is another link in vuforia forums. Definately similer to your issue 
https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-extension-technical-discussion/frozen-stretched-screen

Comment: It can help if you specify what did you try... Anyway - did you look here? https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-extension-technical-discussion/videobackgroundconfig-size-0

Comment: @killer_mech :Thank you for the response. I unchecked Auto Graphics API option in the player settings and deleted Metal from the list. I just have OpenGLES2 now, but still the issue is not resolved

Comment: @yakobom : Thanks for your response. I checked the link that you have provided and confirmed against my settings but the issue is still there. As mentioned above, I unchecked Auto Graphics API checkbox and also unchecked Auto in lighting->Settings.

Comment: This issue maybe specifically with ios 11.3 with xcode 9.3.  https://forum.unity.com/threads/ios-11-3-crash.526638/ . @KavitaKanwar can you check on older ios version if possible and test if the bug is getting reproduced in that? If you dont have any spare device try this switching to xcode 9.2 as mentioned in thread and try running in  your ipX https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/ios/resolution-vuforia-7-ios-113-black-screen-problem.

Comment: Another question i have is @KavitaKanwar is that are you getting 'OPENGL NATIVE PLUG-IN ERROR: GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION:' error in log or something else because i saw many different types of errors for "VideoBackgroundConfig with screen size of zero received, skipping config step" based on this search. The log above added is your log or the bounty added person log? If it is not your log can you post the entire error log?

Comment: Just for anyone else Vuforia has put the above thing in sticky in their forums https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/ar-technical-discussion/ios. https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/ios/known-issue-when-developing-vuforia-7-xcode-93-and-ios-113-beta-arkit-15. Hope this helps someone to get pointers. This might be possibly a bug in vuforia in itself.

Comment: @killer_mech: I created another project in Unity 2017.2.0f3 and it worked fine on iOS 11.3 and XCode 9.3 beta. I will try to run this earlier project on some other iOS version and will let you know if it works. In case it doesn't work, I'll post my logs. The logs posted above are not from my project.

Comment: One of the posts and below answer also suggest to reimport vuforia. Did you tried reimporting vuforia just for ios? One more question is did you create this project in mac unity? or windows version of unity. I remember going through one of the posts mentioning need to reimport vuforia. The new project you created in mac and it worked with vuforia imported in mac? If it is then might as well try to reimport the vuforia for mac.

Comment: Both the projects were created on Mac. Only difference between the two is that the first one in which I am facing issues has been created using Unity 2017.3.1f1 and the second one that worked fine was created using Unity 2017.2.0f3

Answer (score 1):

This video shows how to solve this issue. Basically it is a XCode 9.3 bug. You need to copy an old XCode iOS 11.3 framework folder to the XCode 9.3.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3roMSonIG5c

Answer (score 0):

Did you initially create your project on Windows ? And then transfer to OSX ?
It is possible that some version of unity or xcode or vuforia don't run on OSX... You should re-import Vuforia after transfering to OSX.

It could also be due to the `Lightning` parameters, go to `Windows`>`Lightning` then `Lightmaps` tab. Uncheck `Auto` then rebuild, upload to iOS and try it again.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I created my project on Mac. I also unchecked Auto Generate check box near Generate Lighting button in Window->Lighting->Settings, but it did not work