# Vuforia + Unity build for iPhone X iOS 11.4 black screen

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, vuforia, iphone-x

I'm using:
XCode 9.4
Unity 2018.1
Vuforia 7.1.31

This problem is strange. I manage to build and run this project using the same XCode for iPhone 6 running iOS 11.4. With the same configuration, it only shows me blank screen on iPhone X iOS 11.4.

Anybody have the same experience with me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49815982/issues-in-ar-app-built-in-unity-using-vuforia-sdk/49895509#49895509 Check your log and you should see the error message from this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update to the latest Vuforia in order to fix this, the reason you only see this in iPhone X is because it supports ARKit and Vuforia has some compatibility issues since ARKit 1.5 came out.

Vuforia 7.1.34 and above fixed this issue https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Release_Notes/Vuforia-SDK-Release-Notes

Comment: I'll try your answer

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution, it works for me.

In unity Player Setting >> other settings>> Memoryless Depth set to unused.

Vuforia works fine in android, when built for IOS I am facing the black screen Issue. I solved this using the above settings.